# How to define global environment variables in Odoo enterprise?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-enterprise

I would like to know how to  declare global variable and call it in any module.
In community used os.getenv(), in enterprise I've switch to this one:
A Python request such as:

Set param and value,

```
self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('global.variable', global_variable )
```

Get value:

```
global_variable = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('global.variable')
```

I think it is not very efficient as I will make many calls to the database, for all global variables that I have.
Any tips/suggestions for improvement are welcome...

Comment: `os.getenv()` is a base functions provided by python os module, you can use it in any odoo versions, you just need to add environment variable to you OS

Comment: That's the question how to define them in Odoo enterprise?

Comment: Set enviroment variables to your OS not Odoo, are you using Odoo.sh or self host?

Comment: Im using odoo.sh, I do not know where to put them there...and the only work around that found was to put them in the model ir.config_parameter... any idea where I can set them in OS?

Comment: Why you think it isn't efficient? how many calls are you doing? PS: You don't neet to set parameters by Python code, you achieve that with a simple xml data record with noupdate="1".  If you use OS enviroments you have to do the same every time you install/migrate your inplementation.